# KOPS: Kubernetes Cluster with private networking on AWS VPC: Error Listing Nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, vpc, kops

I followed this tutorial: [Kubernetes Cluster with private networking on AWS using Kops](https://kubecloud.io/setting-up-a-highly-available-kubernetes-cluster-with-private-networking-on-aws-using-kops-65f7a94782ef)

However, after creating the kubernetes cluster, I am getting the following error:

```
$ kops validate cluster
Using cluster from kubectl context: k8s-cluster.mydomain.com
Validating cluster k8s-cluster.mydomain.com
```

### Error Message:

```
unexpected error during validation: error listing nodes: Get https://subdomain.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/v1/nodes: EOF
```

Any ideas on how to debug or resolve this issue?

---

Steps I used to create are below:

**Setup VPC and Subnets**

Create the VPC

```
$ aws ec2 create-vpc --cidr-block 10.0.0.0/16 --region eu-central-1
```

Allow DNS hostnames

```
$ aws ec2 modify-vpc-attribute --vpc-id ${VPC_ID} --enable-dns-hostnames "{\"Value\":true}" --region ${REGION}
```

Create internet gateway

```
$ aws ec2 create-internet-gateway --region ${REGION}
```

Attach internet gateway to VPC

```
$ aws ec2 attach-internet-gateway --internet-gateway-id ${INTERNET_GATEWAY_ID} --vpc-id ${VPC_ID} --region ${REGION}
```

[PUBLIC SUBNETS] Create three public zones / subnets (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 create-subnet --vpc-id ${VPC_ID} --cidr-block 10.0.0.0/20 --availability-zone ${AVAILABILITY_ZONE_1} --region ${REGION}
```

Set public subnets to auto-assign public ip to instances (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 modify-subnet-attribute --subnet-id ${PUBLIC_SUBNET_1} --map-public-ip-on-launch --region ${REGION}
```

[PRIVATE SUBNETS] Create three private zones / subnets (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 create-subnet --vpc-id ${VPC_ID} --cidr-block 10.0.48.0/20 --availability-zone ${AVAILABILITY_ZONE_1} --region ${REGION}
```

[Setup NAT Gateways] Allocate address (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 allocate-address --domain vpc --region ${REGION}
```

Create NAT gateway for public zones (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 create-nat-gateway --subnet-id ${PUBLIC_SUBNET_1} --allocation-id ${EIP_ALLOCATION_ID_1} --region ${REGION}
```

[CONFIGURE ROUTE TABLES] Create route table

```
$ aws ec2 create-route-table --vpc-id ${VPC_ID} --region ${REGION}
```

Create route for internet gateway

```
$ aws ec2 create-route --route-table-id ${RTB_PUBLIC_1} --destination-cidr-block 0.0.0.0/0 --gateway-id ${INTERNET_GATEWAY_ID} --region ${REGION}
```

Associate public subnets with route table (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 associate-route-table --route-table-id ${RTB_PUBLIC_1} --subnet-id ${PUBLIC_SUBNET_1} --region ${REGION}
```

[ROUTE TABLE FOR PRIVATE ZONES] Create route table for each private zone (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 create-route-table --vpc-id ${VPC_ID} --region ${REGION}
```

Create route to NAT Gateway (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 create-route --route-table-id ${RTB_PRIVATE_1} --destination-cidr-block 0.0.0.0/0 --nat-gateway-id ${NAT_GW_1} --region ${REGION}
```

Associate subnets (3x)

```
$ aws ec2 associate-route-table --route-table-id ${RTB_PRIVATE_1} --subnet-id ${PRIVATE_SUBNET_1} --region ${REGION}
```

---

**Other Configuration**

Set up S3 Bucket as Kops state store

```
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my-state-store --region ${REGION} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-central-1
```

Create cluster

```
$ kops create cluster --node-count 3 --zones ${AVAILABILITY_ZONE_1},${AVAILABILITY_ZONE_2},${AVAILABILITY_ZONE_3} --master-zones ${AVAILABILITY_ZONE_1},${AVAILABILITY_ZONE_2},${AVAILABILITY_ZONE_3} --state ${KOPS_STATE_STORE} --dns-zone=${DNS_ZONE_PRIVATE_ID} --dns private --node-size m5.large --master-size m5.large --topology private --networking weave --vpc=${VPC_ID} --bastion ${NAME}
```

Edit cluster to config subnets

```
$ kops edit cluster ${NAME}
```

Note: update subnets to correspond with created public/private subnets above

```
$ kops update cluster ${NAME} --yes
```

Answer (score 4):

Issue resolved. It was not a `kops` problem, the issue was with AWS M5 and linux version.

> The kops default Debian jessie images do not support nvme for EBS
>   volumes, which is used by the AWS M5 instance types. As a result,
>   masters fail to start, as they can not mount the EBS volumes.

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/4873